# Sending Mail in Android throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I know this question has many answers but still I am asking this question because no answer have solved my problem.

I tried all the fixes that were discussed in the other versions of this question but nothing helped me.

**My code :**

```
package com.blogspot.ram914.flames;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String MAIL = "my e-mail";
private final String PASSWORD = "my password";

EditText etSenderMaildId;
EditText etSenderName;
EditText etRecipientMailId;
EditText etRecipientName;
EditText etMessage;
Button btnSend;

ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
Context context = null;

String RelationName;

static Session session = null;
// First go and Turn on less secure app access to sender mail
static String receiverMailId = "", subject = "", textMessage = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_mail);

    context = this;

    String senderName;
    String senderMailId;
    String receiverName;

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    RelationName = b.getString("relation_name");
    senderName = b.getString("sender_name");
    receiverName = b.getString("recipient_name");

    etSenderMaildId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sender_mail_id);
    etSenderName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
    etRecipientMailId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recipient_mail_id);
    etRecipientName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recipiend_name);
    etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meassage);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    senderMailId = getSenderMailId();
    etSenderMaildId.setText(senderMailId);
    etSenderMaildId.setEnabled(false);

    etSenderName.setText(senderName);
    etSenderName.setEnabled(false);

    etRecipientName.setText(receiverName);
    etRecipientName.setEnabled(false);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(pdialog != null)
        pdialog.dismiss();
    pdialog = null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(pdialog != null)
        pdialog.dismiss();
    pdialog = null;
}

public void sendTo(View view) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    receiverMailId = etRecipientMailId.getText().toString();
    subject = "From Flames App";
    textMessage = getMessageContent();

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SendMail.this.MAIL, SendMail.this.PASSWORD);
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Ram Prasad");
    try{
        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail...", true);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("\n\n\nStatus :","Failed\n\n\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Ram Prasad");
    RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
    task.execute("");
}

public void enableEdit(View view) {
    view.setEnabled(true);
}

public String getSenderMailId() {
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if(account.type.equals("com.google")) {
            return account.name;
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n"+account.name+"\n\n");
    }
    return "your mail id";
}

public String getMessageContent() {
    return "Hi "+etRecipientName.getText().toString()+",\n"+
            "Do you know "+etSenderName.getText().toString()+"?\n"
            +etSenderName.getText().toString()+" played flames with you and got the below relation.\n"
            +RelationName+"\n\n  and \n"
            +etSenderName.getText().toString()+" sent a message for you :\n"
            +etMessage.getText().toString()+" \n\n\n"
            +"Sender : "+etSenderMaildId.getText().toString();
}

private class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
compile            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("rbablu94@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(SendMail.receiverMailId));
            message.setSubject(SendMail.subject);
            message.setText(SendMail.textMessage);
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(pdialog != null)
            pdialog.dismiss();
        pdialog = null;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

And the exception is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax.activation.DataHandler
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1566)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1219)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1607)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1590)
at com.blogspot.ram914.flames.SendMail$RetreiveFeedTask.doInBackground(SendMail.java:168)
at com.blogspot.ram914.flames.SendMail$RetreiveFeedTask.doInBackground(SendMail.java:158)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

And I have added both **mail.jar** and **activation.jar** as libraries.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjZ7j.jpg)

I have been struggling hard to get this code run with out crashing my app.
Can anyone help me??

**EDIT :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$LoginAuthenticator.doAuth(SMTPTransport.java:982)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:927)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:861)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:766)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.blogspot.ram914.flames.SendMail$RetreiveFeedTask.doInBackground(SendMail.java:169)
at com.blogspot.ram914.flames.SendMail$RetreiveFeedTask.doInBackground(SendMail.java:158)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Comment: My problem is different now.

Comment: Open a question with just that error.  Looks like you are using an older version of Android as [StandardCharsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) was added in API level 19.  Try to downgrade to JavaMail 1.5.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are using an old approach.  If so, you are missing a jar.

[image: javamail]

See `javamail` for Android here:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads

*Note: the above project is old and probably not supported anymore.*

If you want to use the new JavaMail 1.6.0, which has Android support, you can grab the `javax.mail.jar` here:
https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases

Then, simply add the dependencies to your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
   compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
}
```

Comment: That works actually. But, My app says Message sent, but I have not received any messages even after 10 minutes.

Comment: Obviously you want the dependencies to use "1.6.0", not "1.5.5".

Comment: If it's still not working, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: I have downloaded that  javax.mail.jar and I added that as a library in my project and I added activation.jar and additional.jar too as libraries.

Comment: I have added the Debug Messages in the EDIT.